# Totem becomes unresponsive when I try to turn off subtitles

Tags: 11.04, totem

The video continues to run with no problems but the interface becomes totally unresponsive, clicking or pressing keys does nothing, and when you try to close it several times a dialog pops up saying the program is unresponsive and if you want to 'Force Quit' it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you open totem from dash or menu, and then from totem menu open the video (instead of opening from Nautilus) this bug also occur?

Comment: I'm using Natty, and yes, this problem happens when loading from File->Open as well.

Comment: Same thing here 11.10 out of the box.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1249785